# iOS 15 build by xcode 13 crash on collectionView performBatchUpdates

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios15, xcode13, ios-15.4

After updating xcode to xcode 13. My app start giving crash on the collectionview where it is using performBatchUpdates on **ios 15**.

It's working fine on lower ios version.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [weakSelf.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:addedIndexPaths];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
   

        // scroll to the last added asset, so the user can see the process of uploading.
        NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = addedIndexPaths.lastObject;
        if (lastIndexPath) {
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [weakSelf.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath
                                                atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
            });
        }
    }];
});
```

Did anybody facing some issue and got some solution with this.

Comment: Actually `performBatchUpdates` is not needed at all. As the name implies it’s for update**s** (plural).

Comment: thanks @vadian for the quick response. Just wanted to know what should I use instead of this.

Comment: Nothing, remove the block.

Comment: then how can I insert the items in collectionView

Comment: As I said the API is only useful for multiple simultaneous insert/delete/move operations. The insert line is treated as **one** operation. It works perfectly fine without the block.